# Property Inheritance in ES6 JS Classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

`/A.js` has the following code;

```
class A {
    constructor(token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
    lok() {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
module.exports = A
```

`/dir1/dir2/B.js` has the following code;

```
let A = require(__dirname + '/../../A.js')
class B extends A {
    constructor(token) {
        super(token)
    }
    tok() {
        return this.token;
    }
}
module.exports = B
```

The question is, how do I inherit the token property from class A, in such a way;

```
let init = new A('123')
init.tok() //will return token
```

Rather my question is, how do I inherit properties declared under constructor from a base class(A) so I can use them in a sub-class(B).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something - you're not using the `B` class anywhere?

Comment: Surely you meant to show `new B('123')` instead of `new A('123')`?

Comment: @mscdex B doesn't have a token by itself, it inherits the token from A so I thought A must be initialized with the token?

Comment: It's the other way around. When you instantiate with `new B('123')` and call [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), it will initialize the constructor of A with the token you've passed in the constructor of B. So you have to do `new B` instead of `new A`

Comment: @AlfenLibe Protip: `require` is always relative to current path, so you never have to use `__dirname` there.

Comment: @Ginden Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When performing the `let init = new A('123')`, you're creating an instance of the `A` class. This means `init` only has the properties and methods of the `A` class, which, notably, means `init` does not have the `tok` method declared on `B`.

If, instead, you perform `let init = new B('123')`, you will create an instance of the `B` class, which inherits the properties of the `A` class also.

`super(token)` in the constructor for `B` means that the constructor for `A` is called with the parameter `token`, therefore you set `this.token = token`. You can then take your `B`-instance `init` and call `tok` on it successfully:

```
let init = new B('123')
init.tok() // '123'
```

You could also still call `lok` on this `init`, as any `B` instance inherits it from `A`:

```
init.lok() // 'hello'
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination!!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue has more to do with the fact that any object of type `A` *does not* have the `tok()` method because that is only in the `B` class. While `A` *does* have the `token` property, it doesn't have the ability to retrieve it using the method. For example, you could this:

```
let init = new A('123')
// init.tok() // this will never work as the method only exists on `B` objects
console.log( .init.token ); // this will work fine because you add the property in the constructor
```

Comment: Short and sweet, nice explaination! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sure thing, but @robin-james' answer has a bit more meat on it. :) Glad you selected that one.